Can a witness for a sinful action function as a witness for non sinful aspects of the action?
There is a wedding that is forbidden but still effective (the participants will actually be married). There are no kosher witness at the wedding. Two kosher witnesses walk in and warn the man that the marriage he is about to enter into is forbidden and then he proceeds.
The witness came to witness the sin, but do they count as witnesses for the marriage?
What about witnessing a man buy a field on Shabbat?

Is the marriage/purchase itself not the sin?

It is the sin but the person becomes married or the new owner.

Exactly, @Clint Eastwood! So what's the question? If someone is the witness to a prohibited but effective marriage, they are a witness to it. Same goes for your land sale example.

I want to know if your summary is true.

A witness is a witness, whether he witnesses a sin or a mitzvah.

This seems related to the question of dividing testimony if someone says for example that he borrowed money with interest.  We believe him that he borrowed money & ignore that he willingly agreed to pay interest which would make him an invalid witness (the more commonly cited example is racier, so I prefer this one).
